# React-Chart-JS-2 ^3.0.5 | TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'visible') at Chart._getSortedDatasetMetas

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

I am making an Area chart with two datasets, and this mysterious error has popped up and stumped me. The chart will render and look fine, but will randomly error out and I'm not sure what is going wrong.

Chart Looks like this:

[image: What the chart looks like]
[What the chart looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZRSA.png)

Screenshot of error:

[image: Error Screenshot]
[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ15F.png)

Code to generate chart

```js
const ChartWrapper = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
`;

const HomeSubmissionsChart = ({
  submissions,
}) => {

  const daySubmissions = getSubmissionsByDayStats(submissions)
  const dataOne = Object.values(daySubmissions).map(obj => obj.subs);
  const dataTwo = Object.values(daySubmissions).map(obj => obj.pass)

  const chartData = (canvas) => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 160);
    gradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(158,158,158,0.5)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(158,158,158,0.16)');

    const passedGradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 160);
    passedGradient.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(100,181,246,1)');
    passedGradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(100,181,246,0.1)');

    
    return {
      labels: Object.keys(daySubmissions).map(val => format(new Date(val), 'MMM-dd')),
      datasets: [
        {
          fill: {
            target: 'origin',
            above: gradient,
          },
          borderColor: 'rgba(158,158,158,.05)',
          pointBorderColor: 'slategrey',
          pointBorderWidth: 1,
          tension: 0.4,
          pointBackgroundColor: 'slategrey',
          data: dataOne,
        },
        {
           fill: {
            target: 'origin',
            above: passedGradient,
           },
          borderColor: 'rgba(100,181,246,.05)',
          pointBorderColor: '#64b5f6',
          pointBorderWidth: 1,
          tension: 0.4,
          pointBackgroundColor: '#64b5f6',
          data: dataTwo,
        },
      ],
    };
  };

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Typography variant="subtitle2" mb={2}>
        Engagement Last 14 Days
      </Typography>
      <LengendWrapper>
        <LegendItem>
          <LegendSubmission />
          <span>
            All Submissions
          </span>
        </LegendItem>
        <LegendItem>
          <LegendPassed />
          <span>
            Modules Passed
          </span>
        </LegendItem>
      </LengendWrapper>
      <ChartWrapper>
        <Line data={chartData} options={options} />
      </ChartWrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  )
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Still struggling with this. The error is occuring when the chart re-renders, but not the first time it renders, and im confused why. I feel like maybe im just missing one little thing but i can't figuire it out.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading to version 3.0.4 fixed it for me.

There is an open issue for tracking: https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/issues/735

Comment: Thanks for your response.. unfortunately i had to upgrade to 3.0.5 for a different bug.